# PlayFramework: Form regex validation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm going to develop a custom validation with usage of regex and `Forms` in play 2.3
According to official documentation I've developed:

```
  case class AlphaNumeric(str: String)

  val anForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "str" -> alphaNumCheck
    )(AlphaNumeric.apply)(AlphaNumeric.unapply)
  )

  val numberConstraint = """\d+""".r
  val alphaNumConstraint: Constraint[String] = Constraint("constraints.password")({
    plainText =>
      val errors = numberConstraint.findFirstIn(plainText) match {
        case None => Nil
        case Some(_) => Seq(ValidationError("Need to contain at least one number"))
      }
      if (errors.isEmpty) {
        Valid
      } else {
        Invalid(errors)
      }
  })

  val alphaNumCheck: Mapping[String] = nonEmptyText.verifying(alphaNumConstraint)

  def alphaNumAction() = Action {
    implicit request => {

      anForm.bindFromRequest fold (
        formWithErrors => {
          BadRequest(anForm.errorsAsJson)
        },
        newAccountInfo => {
          Ok(Json.obj("message" -> "success"))
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

But when I do a call of this action I receive 500 Internal Server error.

```
Internal server error, for (POST) [/alpha] ->

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:137) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:137) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$13$$anon$14.call(Router.scala:217) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at play.core.Router$Routes$TaggingInvoker.call(Router.scala:464) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:137) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.api.data.ObjectMapping5.<init>(ObjectMappings.scala:272) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at play.api.data.Forms$.mapping(Forms.scala:77) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at controllers.AccountController$.<init>(AccountController.scala:71) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.AccountController$.<clinit>(AccountController.scala) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:137) ~[na:na]
[error] application - Error while rendering default error page
```

When I change custom `alphaNumCheck` on some standard e.g. `nonEmptyText` everything is ok.

The question is how to do correctly custom validation with regex?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367718/custom-regex-validation-in-play-framework-scala/24368253#24368253

Comment: All is ok, change order. Add `val alphaNumCheck: Mapping[String] =` before `val anForm =` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive NullPointerException - `alphaNumCheck` is null. Move

```
val alphaNumCheck: Mapping[String] = nonEmptyText.verifying(alphaNumConstraint)
```

to the top of `val anForm =`

See simple example:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A {

val a = b

val b = "AAA"

}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:9: warning: Reference to uninitialized value b
       val a = b
               ^
defined class A

scala> val instance = new A
instance: A = A@4ac68d3e

scala> instance.a
res3: String = null
```

The problem is with initialization order. `a` is created before `b` - in line `val a = b` b has value null.

If I add `lazy` all will be OK.

```scala
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A {

lazy val a = b

val b = "AA" 
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A

scala> val instance = new A
instance: A = A@d7b1517

scala> instance.a
res4: String = AA
```